# Combining powershell & cmd to create a batch file

Tags: powershell

I am not a coder but I have some basic ability to mash some scripts together and usually get something that works for me, but this is way beyond my comprehension. I am trying to combine 3 things into a batch file. It's essentially an all in one solution to turn Windows 10 privacy settings off and to remove some background apps. I can run the commands just fine in powershell, but I wanted to automate the entire thing through one batch script:

1. Keep the windows 10 privacy settings script up to date. This is done through the following command in powershell:

   ```
   (New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hahndorf/Set-Privacy/master/Set-Privacy.ps1') | out-file .\Set-Privacy.ps1 -force
   ```

Just need to make sure that the destination folder for download is set first (I have no idea how to do this through a batchfile/script). The command comes from the script that someone wrote on github located [here](https://github.com/hahndorf/Set-Privacy/blob/master/README.md)

2. Run the powershell script to turn privacy settings off, on the highest setting. This is done through the following command, again from the link above:

   ```
   .\Set-Privacy.ps1 -Strong -admin
   ```
3. Remove background apps, for example, removing "3D Builder":

To uninstall 3D Builder:

```
get-appxpackage *3dbuilder* | remove-appxpackage
```

Details on this found [here](https://www.askvg.com/guide-how-to-remove-all-built-in-apps-in-windows-10/)

Any help with any of this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,  of course PowerShell is not a batch file tool per se, though you can use it to call a batch (.bat,.cmd.vbs, etc.) file.

Though a script is a script (batch or otherwise), taxonomy is a whole different conversation.

So, what you want is a function you can call as needed.

```
Function Set-Windows10PrivacySettings
                                                                                                {
[CmdletBinding()]

[Alias()]

Param
(
    [string]$DownloadPath = "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads"
)

# Download the Privacy Script
(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hahndorf/Set-Privacy/master/Set-Privacy.ps1') | 
out-file "$env:USERPROFILE\Downloads\Set-Privacy.ps1"

# Temporarialy naviagte to the target directory adn run the script
Push-Location -Path $DownloadPath
Start-Process .\Set-Privacy.ps1 -Strong -admin

# Remove AppX packages
$AppPackageList = (Get-AppxPackage).Name | 
Sort-Object | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Select one or more AppX to remove. Press CRTL+LeftMouseClick to multi-select' -PassThru

# Remove the selected AppX without prompt to confirm
ForEach($AppPackage in $AppPackageList)
{
    "Removing selected AppX $AppPackage"
    # Remove-AppxPackage -Package $_ -Confirm:$false -WhatIf
}

# Retrun to the original directory
Pop-Location
}

# Call the function in PowerShell
Set-Windows10PrivacySettings
```

Just remove the comment marker '#' and the 'WhatIf' switch to actually allow things to happen.